# Add a text before getting the data from database codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just want to ask if how can I add a text before getting the data from database . My code looks like this

```
$GTextension = 'GT-';
    $UTextension = 'UT-';
    $rec_type = array(1472,1416,9752,1417,1500);//international,manila,province
    $last_receipt = $this->ion_auth->getLastReceipt($receipt);
    if($last_receipt->num_rows() > 0){
        if($receipt == 1){
            $newreceipt = $last_receipt->row()->inv_cno+1;
        }
        elseif($receipt == 2){
            $newreceipt = $last_receipt->row()->inv_cno+1;
        }
        elseif($receipt == 3){
            $newreceipt = $last_receipt->row()->inv_cno+1;
        }
        elseif($receipt == 4){
            $newreceipt = $last_receipt->row()-> $UTextension. inv_cno+1;
        }
```

so is it possible to add a text before the data . Here's what i need to add the text

```
elseif($receipt == 4){
            $newreceipt = $last_receipt->row()-> $UTextension. inv_cno+1;
        }
```

so it would look like this

`DR: UT-0001;`

Comment: so you want to plus 1 everydata ?

Comment: yes but i need to add a text on the receipt == 4 because it's a different receipt sir.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson not working sir

Comment: Sorry, it should be: `$UTextension . ($last_receipt->row()->inv_cno+1);`. If that doesn't work, please elaborate.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it doesn't print out sir the text before the incrementation

Comment: @MagnusEriksson but the problem is that it doesn't increment when it has an extension.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sir?

Answer (score 0):

first check @MagnusEriksson comment.

then try to add this

```
elseif($receipt == 4){
            $newreceipt = ++$last_receipt->row()->inv_cno;
            $newreceipt = $UTextension.$newreceipt;
 }
```

if there is an error please put in comment

Comment: It doesn't print out the extension

Comment: You need to change it to: `$UTextension . ($last_receipt->row()->inv_cno + 1);`.

Comment: I tried this and now everytime i add it also adds the extension like this (first add) UT-1419 (second add) UT-UT-1419 (third add) UT-UT-UT-1419

Comment: but when i put it this way `$newreceipt = $UTextension.(++$last_receipt->row()->inv_cno);` it increments but still like this (first add) UT-1419 (second add) UT-UT-1420 like that

Comment: it only increments the extension not the number sir . that's what happening on your code.

Comment: `echo ++$last_receipt->row()->inv_cno`. what is the result ? is it incrementing ?

Comment: @MyNameIs nope it's not incrementing sir . but when i do this `$newreceipt = $UTextension.(++$last_receipt->row()->inv_cno);` it is incrementing but also adds a lot of extenstions. like UT-UT-UT-UT 1420, UT-UT-UT-UT-UT-UT 1421 like that